# Shifting blog from blogger to wordpress - retain traffic

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, blogger

We have a popular blog hosted on the blogger platform with a custom domain name. We want to move it to a self hosted WordPress website with the same domain. The blog has an authority on 8/10 to 9/10 on certain keywords and a global page rank of 300k. I would like to retain the authority and page rank so I don't lose on my readership or ad revenue. While I have transitioned the data to the new website, I am unable to figure out what needs to be done to retain pagerank. Can someone guide me to the steps needed for this? The question is possibly a little subjective and I am not looking for opinion on specifically how to implement but more of a guideline on what steps are necessary.. some tips and tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is much concern here about authority or page rank since you are not changing domain names.

The only thing that will come into play are your URLs linking to your blog entries.

If the URLs change you would simply place 301 redirects in your `.htaccess` file.